# Retrieving jpg image from url returns nil. However, retrieving png image from url works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

If I use the following code and the data will be nil

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.manipalgrocer.com/image/catalog/BANNER/sweets.jpg"]];
    img = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        menuCell.imgMenu.image = img;
    });
});
```

However, If I use the following code I will get the image in my menuCell

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.fooodzapp.com/image/catalog/JUST%20CHILL/Justchill%20(1).png"]];
    img = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        menuCell.imgMenu.image = img;
    });
});
```

If any one knows how to resolve this please reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in the console when trying to load the http URL?

Comment: First add ATS in your plist, check for image url there must be any extra space. Then call service

Answer (score 5):

your first image is **HTTP** you need to add  **App Transport Security** to yes in list

[image]

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Abdelahad Darwish. Everything works fine now